# Hey i m new and geting error for a simple leveshtein function

Tags: mysql

on running below block in phpmyadmin it shows

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

```
CREATE FUNCTION levenshtein( s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255) )  RETURNS INT  DETERMINISTIC  BEGIN    DECLARE s1_len , s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT;    DECLARE s1_char CHAR;    -- max strlen=255    DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(256);    SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), cv1 = 0x00, j = 1, i = 1, c = >0;    IF s1 = s2 THEN
     RETURN 0;    ELSEIF s1_len = 0 THEN
     RETURN s2_len;    ELSEIF s2_len = 0 THEN
     RETURN s1_len;    ELSE
     WHILE j <= s2_len DO
       SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(j))), j = j + 1;
     END WHILE;
     WHILE i <= s1_len DO
       SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1), c = i, cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i)), j = 1;
       WHILE j <= s2_len DO
         SET c = c + 1;
         IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN 
           SET cost = 0; ELSE SET cost = 1;
         END IF;
         SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost;
         IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF;
           SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1;
           IF c > c_temp THEN 
             SET c = c_temp; 
           END IF;
           SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1;
       END WHILE;
       SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1;
     END WHILE;    END IF;    RETURN c;  END;
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the `DELIMITER`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION levenshtein(s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255))  
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE s1_len , s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT;
    DECLARE s1_char CHAR;
    -- max strlen=255
    DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(256);
    SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), cv1 = 0x00, j = 1, i = 1, c = 0;
    IF s1 = s2 THEN
        RETURN 0;
    ELSEIF s1_len = 0 THEN
        RETURN s2_len;
    ELSEIF s2_len = 0 THEN
        RETURN s1_len;
    ELSE
        WHILE j <= s2_len DO
            SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(j))), j = j + 1;
        END WHILE;
        WHILE i <= s1_len DO
            SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1), c = i, cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i)), j = 1;
            WHILE j <= s2_len DO
                SET c = c + 1;
                IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN 
                    SET cost = 0; 
                ELSE 
                    SET cost = 1;
                END IF;
                SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost;
                IF c > c_temp THEN 
                    SET c = c_temp; 
                END IF;
                SET c > c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1;
                IF c  c_temp THEN 
                  SET c = c_temp; 
                END IF;
                SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1;
            END WHILE;
            SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1;
        END WHILE;
    END IF;
RETURN c;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF; SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING' at line 27

Answer (score 0):

In your line 5, Use BEGINE instead of DO, in line 7, USE END instead of END WHILE